# How to stop (and restart) the Rails Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, terminal, restart

I'm following the instructions here http://railsinstaller.org/mac to get up and running with Rails on a Mac running OS X 10.8.2

At step 8 I'm asked to restart Rails server but how?

I'm assuming via a command line, but from within the already open ruby terminal window or a new one?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Press `Ctrl+C`

When you start the server it mentions this in the startup text.

Comment: OK that did it - and to restart it enter `rails server` into the open window or start a new one?

Comment: Excellent thanks, will show this as answered in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 47):

Now in rails 5 you can do:

```
rails restart
```

The output of `rails --tasks`:

> Restart app by touching tmp/restart.txt

I think that is usefully if you run rails as a demon

Comment: Especially, when using Docker.

Comment: `rails -v` = `5.2.0`... but `rails restart` gives me a usage menu for `rails new`?  Did they already remove this command?

Comment: In the source of rails on github not have any new changes, you can look at: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/restart.rake

Answer (score 28):

On OSX, you can take advantage of the UNIX-like command line - here's what I keep handy in my .bashrc to enable me to more easily restart a server that's running in background (-d) mode (note that you have to be in the Rails root directory when running this):

```
alias restart_rails='kill -9 `cat tmp/pids/server.pid`; rails server -d'
```

My initial response to the comment by @zane about how the PID file isn't removed was that it might be behavior dependent on the Rails version or OS type. However, it's also possible that the shell runs the second command (`rails server -d`) sooner than the `kill` can actually cause the previous running instance to stop.

So alternatively, `kill -9 cat tmp/pids/server.pid && rails server -d` might be more robust; or you can specifically run the `kill`, wait for the `tmp/pids` folder to empty out, then restart your new server.

Comment: Using kill -9 leaves the pid file on my system, meaning that starting the server again will result in a "server already running" error (and the server will not start again). Use kill with out "-9", this will remove the pid file.

Comment: @Zane - you might want to say something about your Rails and OS versions. On OSX 10.8, with Rails 4+, an "orphaned" PID file caused due to  `kill -9`, aka, `SIGKILL`, does _not_ cause the "Server already running" message to be output.

Comment: sameers: good point, and interesting that behavior is different. OS: Linux manjaro 3.16.7.4-1-MANJARO Rails: 4.2.0.

Comment: This results in `Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)` when the server restarts for me.

Comment: @Qwertie you will have to say more - I can't reproduce on Rails5.2.2; OSX Mojave

Comment: I was testing on fedora 29, it might work differently.

Answer (score 0):

In case that doesn't work there is another way that works especially well in Windows: [Kill localhost:3000 process from Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684915/kill-localhost3000-process-from-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

if you are not able to find the rails process to kill it might actually be not running. Delete the tmp folder and its sub-folders from where you are running the rails server and try again.

Answer (score -1):

I had to restart the rails application on the production so I looked for an another answer. I have found it below:

http://wiki.ocssolutions.com/Restarting_a_Rails_Application_Using_Passenger

Answer (score -2):

I just reboot the server with

`Ctrl + c`

That worked for me