# Kill localhost:3000 process from Windows command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, command-line

So im using ruby on rails in windows (i hear you all spitting your coffee onto the screen), its only a short term thing. (using ubuntu at home)  So i tried to fire up webrick this afternoon and i get the error message

```
TCPServer Error, only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted
```

So it seems as if port 3000 is still running from last week? My question is how do i kill the process from the Windows command line. normally i have to press ctrl and pause/break in windows as ctrl c is not working which is only killing the batch process it seems..

Any solutions welcomed

### Edit

So it seems as if

```
tasklist
```

will give me the list of processes, but where do i find the process for running the webrick server?

`ruby.exe` is not listed as a running process

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `netstat -a -o -n` to determine the `pid` of the process running on port 3000. Then you should be able to use `taskkill /pid ####` to kill whatever process is running on that port.

Probably not the most graceful way to do it, but I think it should work.

**EDIT**

You'll probably have to also use the `/F` flag to force-kill the process. I just tried it on my local machine, and that worked fine.

Comment: thank you very much, been searching everywhere for that, yeah im getting access denied, is the syntax taskkill /F pid ###

Comment: yeah, that should do it. So if `netstat` shows a pid of `6688`, then the command would be `taskkill /F /pid 6688`. Also, I tried running it from Git Bash to no avail. Works fine under command prompt though.

Comment: Make sure you're putting a space between those flags!

`taskkill /F /pid ####`

Comment: yes it was my spacing, the command is correct but i am getting access denied so the process cannot be terminated.Would you happen to know why this is?

Comment: its ok i opened up cmd with ctrl shift enter..This gave me admin privelages

Comment: Be careful.  When you forcibly kill the Rails server this way you'll need to ensure you delete `<approot>\tmp\pids\server.pid` afterwards if you intend to start the Rails server again.

Comment: taskkill /F /PID <number-here>

Answer (score 3):

Go into `rails_project\tmp\pids` and delete the .pid file in there.

run:

```
rails server
```